# Finding the derivative of $y=\frac{1}{\left(x+\sqrt{4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3}\right)^4}$

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

Find an expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ given that

$y=\frac{1}{\left(x+\sqrt{4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3}\right)^4}$

To be honest, I don't know how hard this question is supposed to be as it was found in an A-level textbook or if there is a simpler method to use than the one I did. I am fairly sure however that this question would never appear on a standard A-level maths paper. I used the chain rule but there were stages in my working where I'm not quite sure what I'm doing is correct.

The textbook says that the answer is

$-\frac{4x}{\left(x+\sqrt{4+(x^2-1)^3}\right)^5}\left(1+\frac{3(x^2-1)^2}{\sqrt{4+(x^2-1)^3}}\right)$

But I am getting

$-\frac{4}{\left(x+\sqrt{4+(x^2-1)^3}\right)^5}\left(1+\frac{3(x^2-1)^2}{2x\sqrt{4+(x^2-1)^3}}\right)$

and online derivative calculators say

$-\frac{4}{\left(x+\sqrt{4+(x^2-1)^3}\right)^5}\left(1+\frac{3x(x^2-1)^2}{\sqrt{4+(x^2-1)^3}}\right)$

I am quite certain they are not equivalent, but I have no way of checking which is correct. How should one approach a question like this? Perhaps a solution done on paper would be quicker, I don't mind.

Comment: For me the correct answer is the last one. You forgot that $(x^2-1)^3$ is itself the composition of two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking this step by step, apply the chain rule once to achieve:

$${\mathrm dy \over \mathrm dx} = -{4\over u^5}{\mathrm du \over \mathrm dx}\quad \quad u = x+\sqrt{4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3}$$

Finding ${\mathrm du \over \mathrm dx}$:

$${\mathrm du \over \mathrm dx} = \left(1+{1\over 2\sqrt v}{\mathrm dv \over \mathrm dx}\right)\quad \quad v = 4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3$$

Finding ${\mathrm dv \over \mathrm dx}$:

$${\mathrm dv \over \mathrm dx} = 3\left(x^2-1\right)^2\cdot 2x$$

And substituting back:

$$\begin{align} {\mathrm dy \over \mathrm dx} &= -{4\over \left(x+\sqrt{4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3}\right)^5}\cdot \left(1+{1\over 2\sqrt{4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3}} \cdot 3\left(x^2-1\right)^2\cdot 2x\right) \\
&= -{4\over \left(x+\sqrt{4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3}\right)^5}\cdot \left(1+{3x\left(x^2-1\right)^2\over \sqrt{4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3}}\right) \\
\end{align}$$

It looks like you forgot to consider the chain rule for $\left(x^2-1\right)^3$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Is there meant to be a 4 in the numerator of the first fraction? Somewhere in my working I did use u=x²-1 and v=4+u³. I will go through it once more tomorrow morning but it looks like the derivative calculators are giving the correct answer and the textbook is wrong.

Comment: @s.xw I made a mistake in the chain rule, the $4$ is supposed to be there! As for the $x$, I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: @s.xw Perhaps your textbook's authors' forgot to take the derivative of $x$ and factored it out to get $x$ on the outside? Either way, it's wrong and the only calculators seem right here. Your calculation was wrong because you forgot the extra $2x$ for $x^2-1$.

Comment: Ah I think I see now. At one point I had $v=4+u^3$ where $u=x^2-1$. So I did dv/du, giving me $3u^2$, but I forgot to then multiply that by du/dx, which is $2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$a=x+\sqrt{4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3}$

$b=4+\left(x^2-1\right)^3$

$c=(x^2+1)$

Then

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}a^{-4}=-4a^{-5}\frac{d}{dx}a$

$\frac{d}{dx}a=1+\frac{d}{dx}b^{\frac{1}{2}}=1+\frac{1}{2}b^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{d}{dx}b$

$\frac{d}{dx}b=0+\frac{d}{dx}c^{3}=3c^{2}\frac{d}{dx}c$

$\frac{d}{dx}c=2x$

Therefore, $\frac{dy}{dx}=-4a^{-5}(1+\frac{1}{2}b^{-\frac{1}{2}}3c^{2}2x)=-4a^{-5}(1+3xc^{2}b^{-\frac{1}{2}})$

$=-\frac{4}{\left(x+\sqrt{4+(x^2-1)^3}\right)^5}\left(1+\frac{3x(x^2-1)^2}{\sqrt{4+(x^2-1)^3}}\right)$

Comment: Thanks. This is very similar to my own solution and makes it clear where I went wrong. I think I used too many unnecessary substitutions, which caused confusion.

Comment: @s.xw You are welcome. I think the substitutions make the structure clear and easy to work with.